# How can I get the value of two specific cells in the DataGridView and store them in variables

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I get the variables that are in two specific columns in DataGridView, for example I want the Id that is in the first column and the name that is on the third. How can I do that? I'm trying the `RowEnter` event but when I searched online I can't find anything that I can follow up. Thanks guys.

```
private void dataGridViewDocumentos_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow dgvr = dataGridViewDocumentos.SelectedRows[0];
    dgvr.Cells[];

    foreach (DataGridViewRow Datarow in contentTable_dgvr.Rows)
    {
        if (dgvr.Value != null && Datarow.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            int contentJobId = 0;
            contentJobId = Datarow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
               
            contentValue2 = Datarow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(contentValue1);
            MessageBox.Show(contentValue2);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have right now, as you guys can see I'm missing a lot of things, I'm not familiar with this so if you guys can point what I need to do I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit marc_s think you can help me out with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the 1st question is, is this on a button click outside the grid? Or is this in response to an specific event that has happens?  The reason why I ask that is because in your code sample you are using the RowEnter event which will fire everytime the row recieves input.   I am not sure if that is what you want ot not.

Anyway, I mean you are pretty much there with your code sample.  If you want to get the selected 1st and 3rd column for the selected row you could use this code.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var activeCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    var fistColumnCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

    var thirdColumnCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];

    MessageBox.Show(fistColumnCell.Value.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(thirdColumnCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Notice that the 2nd paramater of the function named `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` has properties for `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` which you can use to get the currently selected row.

However, if this code should fire in response to a user double clicking a cell you could use the `CellDoubleClick` event

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var fistColumnCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

        var thirdColumnCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];

        MessageBox.Show(fistColumnCell.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(thirdColumnCell.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  its what i wanted to do, now i can use variables i get for a new query im going to do to fill a new datagrid

Comment: Excellent. Pleased it helped.